# VMwaree Workstation. Estimate bandwidth between guest and host systems

Tags: virtual-machines, bandwidth

How can be measured the bandwidth speed between Windows 8.1 as host OS and [Turnkey LAMP](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/lampstack) (Debian I guess) stack as guest?

Comment: (I'll use the guest as a server using a 20/200 Mbps connection, looking for 1 Gbps)

Comment: @hopelessn00b The stack will be used like a private server for a commercial system, accessed through an ip. Is off-topic? Even though there was a comment refering to an use as a server. I thought it was enough a concise question.

Comment: Read the off-topic reason.  Using a client OS as a virtualization host is not a reasonable IT practice, not is it a supported server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

[**There are numerous utilities**](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-monitor-network/) to measure bandwidth speed on a Linux system.

I recommend *nethogs* (#4) to measure the bandwidth of your application specifically.

It doesn't matter what kind of network connection it is. Physical, VMware host-only network, VMware bridged network, etc.

```
# ubuntu or debian (default repos)
$ sudo apt-get install nethogs
$ sudo nethogs
```